# populate a div-table from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

trying to dynamically populate a div from code behind, with a table, and each time the loop goes round add another row to the table....

```
Table table = new Table();
            table.ID = "Table1";
            mapInnerDiv.Controls.Add(table);

            foreach (Layer l in Layers)
            {
                string splitURL = l.URL.Split('/')[7];

                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();

                TextBox tb = new TextBox();

                tb.ID = splitURL;

                    // Add the control to the TableCell
                    cell.Controls.Add(tb);
                    // Add the TableCell to the TableRow
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
            }
```

the above code does not populate the div. from the console I can see that a table is added to the div, but it is empty.
Adding to the innerHTML such as `mapInnerDiv.InnerHtml = "this is a text post";`
 will display this message but if I use  tags and try to add to the div from here it will prove difficult when adding a new row??

any ideas on where my loop is going wrong thanks

Comment: i dont see `table.Rows.Add(row)` anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs some re-arranging and you need to add the rows to your table.

```
Table table = new Table();
table.ID = "Table1";

foreach (Layer l in Layers)
    {
    string splitURL = l.URL.Split('/')[7];

    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.ID = splitURL;
    // Add the control to the TableCell
    cell.Controls.Add(tb);
    // Add the TableCell to the TableRow
    row.Cells.Add(cell);
    table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
mapInnerDiv.Controls.Add(table);
```

Add the table to the div, after it is fully built.

And make sure that mapInnerDiv is defined as such:

```
<div id="mapInnerDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can see that a table is added to the div, but it is empty

This is because no rows are being added to your table.

Add the following code `table.Rows.Add(row)` to add the row to your `table` underneath this line:

`row.Cells.Add(cell);`